# DBMS_XSLPROCESSOR.CLOB2FILE - Error Invalid Directory path

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, oracle11g

This is the PL/SQL procedure which I am trying to run . The issue I am facing  an invalid directory path. I am running Oracle 11g On windows server. I have a client configured on a different machine which is a linux machine.I tried to check in the init.ora file to set the directory path,but seems like futil package is not supported in 11g Windows oracle version

How can I do import of a single column from a table  where its a XML_clob(XMLs stored in a bunch),column type is CLOB in this case and dump to a file. Appreciate if a better PL/SQL procedure is available for converting the whole column to a single file and store in the directory through the client machine

Appreciate responses for the guidance towards my problem

## UPDATE

```
CREATE or REPLACE PROCEDURE 
process_all_rows
IS
   TYPE clob_aat 
   IS TABLE OF minf100k300wclob%xml_clob 
      INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;  
   l_XML clob_aat;


BEGIN
  select XMLElement(xml_clob).getClobVal()
   BULK COLLECT INTO l_XML
      FROM minf100k300wclob;


FOR indx IN 1 .. L_XML.COUNT  
   LOOP
      dbms_lob.append(L_XML, 'XML_EDI_FILES_1', 'file1.xml', nls_charset_id('AL32UTF8')); 
   END LOOP;
END process_all_rows;
```

I am unable to get this working as I am getting the error as shown below

Errors for PROCEDURE PROCESS_ALL_ROWS:

```
LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
4/4  PL/SQL: Item ignored
5/33     PLS-00208: identifier 'XML_CLOB' is not a legal cursor attribute
12/22    PLS-00382: expression is of wrong type
18/7     PL/SQL: Statement ignored
18/7     PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'APPEND'
SQL> 
enter code here
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Well, to use `clob2file` or most of the functions that rely on `UTL_FILE`, you must create a `directory object` in oracle database first. The syntax is:

```
CREATE DIRECTORY XML_EDI_FILES AS 'C:\path\on\your\server\';
```

This adds specified directory on your server to a special oracle table with the name you specify, in that case `XML_EDI_FILES`. When you call file-related procedures later, you will pass that name as an argument. See [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_5007.htm) for more info. Granted, oracle process on your server must have write permissions to that dir.

2) Wait, through **client** machine? Use sqlplus spool, for example. Rough syntax is

```
set long 4000;
spool output_file.txt
select xml_clob from minf100k300wc
```

Though I can almost guarantee this will not work as desired at first, since sql-plus tends to also output column names, insert line breaks etc. You'll have to look up sqlplus formatting options. I'd probably go with a little bit of Java code instead, Clobs are nicely mapped to strings IIRC.

3) It's not clear what you're asking.

*Answer to updated question:*

...but I even described what you had to do in my comment. Here you go:

```
CREATE or REPLACE PROCEDURE process_all_rows IS
  tmp_clob clob;
  cursor cur_clob is
    select XMLElement(xml_clob).getClobVal() val FROM minf100k300wclob;
begin
  dbms_lob.createtemporary(tmp_clob,true);
  for c in cur_clob loop
    dbms_lob.append(tmp_clob, c.val);
  end loop;
  dbms_xslprocessor.clob2file(tmp_clob, 'XML_EDI_FILES_1', 'file1.xml', nls_charset_id('AL32UTF8'));
  dbms_lob.freetemporary(tmp_clob);
end;
```

Comment: I got the issue resolved for the first issue ,thanks for that .  however I am trying to create a stored procedure to use bulk collect to put the xml files stored in the database  into a variable ,   you can ignore the third issue as I could directly use WINSCP to transfer the dump file created in Oracle database server. I have updated with my stored procedure in the question

Comment: You have a couple of issues in new procedure. two `procedure` keywords, some extra `#` in the middle, `TABLE OF minfclob100k300w%clob` should be `IS TABLE OF minfclob100k300w%xml_clob`, `clob2file` is a procedure not a function so your compilation will fail at `analyze_compensation`, not to mention it's not clear what you're trying to achieve by that. Also, you don't really need bulk collect if you're just looping over them, a simple cursor will do. More importantly, `clob2file` will always overwrite - you need to construct a complete clob with `dbms_lob.append`, then write once.

Comment: I am trying to put the column in the dump file in the database server ,with select xml_clob from <MINF100k300wclob> in the directory pointed in XML_EDI_FILES with filename file1.xml. Could you edit the code and put it if you can understand my issue , yes you are right , I am getting compilation error with clob2 file even after removing analyse_compensation .

Comment: See updated answer. Sorry to be rude, but your main issue is not understanding what are you trying to achieve with your code. Write programs incrementally in little chunks and get each chunk to work flawlessly before moving to next one, don't just throw together a bunch of instructions and hope it works. Also, next time please don't change your question completely, but ask a new one instead.

Comment: Yeah,its my first time trying to get this working ,however I would keep things in mind . Thanks a lot for your new code , I may need some time to grasp it , but I am getting 2 compilation errors .

Comment: LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
8/5  PL/SQL: Statement ignored
8/33  PLS-00302: component 'VALUE' must be declared
SQL>

Comment: There was a typo in my code (there was no "value" column in the query). Now it should work.

Comment: That worked like a charm,however the query is not pulling the xml files stored  from the column xml_clob in the table , its giving as <XML_clob></XML_clob> repetitively. I am am trying to change the query as  select xml_clob from table,but its taking a lots of time executing the proc  and its not displaying any changes in the file too